# I am creating a program that counts up by an increment. I am really close but I can't get the program to go up by the decided increment?

Tags: c++

This is the code. Any suggestions are welcome but I am really trying to learn C++ for a class and not just get answers. So if you could explain how you got to the solution that would be amazing! Thanks for the help!!

```
//Looping
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int increment;
    int input_variable;
    bool stop_printing = true;

    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> input_variable;
    cout << "Increment: ";
    cin >> increment;

    do
    {
        int counter = 0;
        counter = increment++;

        cout << "Result: " << counter << endl;
        increment++;
        if (increment >= input_variable)
        {
            stop_printing = false;
        }
    } while (stop_printing == true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have your `counter` and `increment` confused - counter should change, increment shouldn't. Also "keep printing while stop printing is true and stop printing once stop_printing is false" - thats just awful naming!

Comment: Do we get a pizza party if we ace the midterm?

Comment: Haha I agree I wasn't allowed to change the naming. I was given variable names.

Comment: Do you see that `increment++` appears twice in this code?  Does that follow your logic?

Comment: Sure it is on me! hahah

Comment: Do I not need it twice?

Comment: You need to be able to tell us what the difference is.  What does it do?  What does it do twice?  The trick with programming is being able to be certain about what each instruction does - so you can be certain about what a collection of instructions does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
counter = increment++;
```

to:

```
counter += increment;
```

`variable++` is for adding 1 to the variable. `variable += value` is for adding the second value to the first variable (it's equivalent to `variable = variable + value`).

You have other problems: You're setting `counter` back to `0` every time through the loop; that should be before the loop. You're doing `increment++` a second time in the loop, this isn't needed. And you're testing `increment` against the input variable instead of testing `counter`.

```
int main()
{
    int increment;
    int input_variable;
    bool stop_printing = true;

    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> input_variable;
    cout << "Increment: ";
    cin >> increment;

    int counter = 0;

    do
    {
        counter += increment;

        cout << "Result: " << counter << endl;

        if (counter >= input_variable)
        {
            stop_printing = false;
        }
    } while (stop_printing == true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to pull  `int counter = 0` outside the loop, no?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I forgot about the different types

Comment: I think it's worth noting that increment and decrement are operators that return, and that they have pre and post to that effect if someone wanted a variable to match another's incrementation (++increment returning the incremented result vs increment++ returning the value of increment before it was increased)

Comment: I didn't want to make his head explode, so I didn't think it necessary to mention those details.